# On defining a setter in Python

Tags: python, decorator, getter-setter, python-decorators, magic-methods

Let's say we have the following code:

```
class A:
       def __init__(self):
           self.x = [p for p in range(10)]
        
       def __getitem__(self, key):
           return self.x[key]

a = A()
print a[2] #will return a.x[2] = 2
```

Now how can I define the setter for `a[i]`? How will I define the decorator?

The process for a simple property is really simple but how will Python understand, in this case, that I want to define a setter for `a[i]` (something like `@a[i].setter`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any decorators in your code, nor do you need one to support item assignment.

Just implement the [`object.__setitem__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) for your class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [p for p in range(10)]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.x[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.x[key] = value
```